# React-Router: why redirects to 404 page?

Tags: reactjs

These are all my paths and I would like them to work:

```
export enum RoutesPath {
  HomePage = '/',
  PaymentFailedPage = '/finish/payment-failed',
  PaymentSuccessfulPage = '/finish/payment-successful',
  LoginPage = '/login',
  ResetPasswordPage = '/reset-password',
  DashboardPage = '/dashboard',
  NotFoundPage = '/404',
  UnsubscribePage = '/unsubscribe/:email?',
  SettingsPage = '/settings',
  TrainingPage = '/training/:training?',
  CheckoutPage = '/checkout/:uuid?',
  RegulationsPage = '/legal/regulations',
  PrivacyPolicyPage = '/legal/privacy-policy',
}
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
export function App() {
  useInjectReducer({ key: sliceKey, reducer: reducer });
  useInjectSaga({ key: sliceKey, saga: appSaga });

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet
        titleTemplate="%s | React Boilerplate"
        defaultTitle="React Boilerplate"
      >
        <meta name="description" content="A React Boilerplate application" />
      </Helmet>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={RoutesPath.HomePage} component={HomePage} />
        <Route path={RoutesPath.LoginPage} component={LoginPage} />
        <Route
          exact
          path={RoutesPath.ResetPasswordPage}
          component={ResetPasswordPage}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={RoutesPath.UnsubscribePage}
          component={UnsubscribePage}
        />
        <Route exact path={RoutesPath.CheckoutPage} component={CheckoutPage} />

        <Route
          path={RoutesPath.PaymentSuccessfulPage}
          component={PaymentSuccessfulPage}
        />
        <Route
          path={RoutesPath.PaymentFailedPage}
          component={PaymentFailedPage}
        />
        <Route path={RoutesPath.NotFoundPage} component={NotFoundPage} />

        <LegalPage> //here is {children} !!
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path={RoutesPath.PrivacyPolicyPage}
              component={PrivacyPolicyPage}
            />

            <Route
              path={RoutesPath.RegulationsPage}
              component={RegulationsPage}
            />

            <Redirect to={RoutesPath.NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        </LegalPage>

        <Layout> //here is {children} !!
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path={RoutesPath.DashboardPage}
              component={DashboardPage}
            />

            <Route
              exact
              path={RoutesPath.TrainingPage}
              component={TrainingPage}
            />

            <Route
              exact
              path={RoutesPath.SettingsPage}
              component={SettingsPage}
            />

            <Redirect to={RoutesPath.NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        </Layout>

        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      
      <GlobalStyle />
    </>
  );
}
```

Everything works fine for the component . All paths contained in this component lead to 404. This is caused by the  component declared above.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Commenting out the  component code works fine, but it so happened that I have two components from {children} and I wish it would stay that way.

Comment: What url are you using in your browser?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/dashboard @Yatrix